# Font blocky when color is set to white

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

As is shown in the image below, I have a set of dynamic textfields... when I change the colour of the text to white the text becomes a horrible choppy messy.

[image: dropdown]

The code used to generate the textfields is:

```
private function drawOption(option:MovieClip, state:String)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case "hover" :
                var backgroundColour:Number = _shadow;
                var textColour:Number = 0xffffff;
                break;
            default :
                var backgroundColour:Number = _background;
                var textColour:Number = _shadow;
                break;
        }
        option._x = edgePadding;
        option._y = 1 + edgePadding + (optionPadding * (option.index)) + (optionHeight * option.index);
        option.beginFill(backgroundColour,100);
        option.lineStyle(1,_border,100,true);
        option.moveTo(0,0);
        option.lineTo(_optionWidth,0);
        option.lineTo(_optionWidth,optionHeight);
        option.lineTo(0,optionHeight);
        option.endFill();
        var textfield:TextField = option.createTextField("string", option.getNextHighestDepth(), 20, 2, _optionWidth, optionHeight);
        textfield.text = option.string;
        textfield.antiAliasType = "normal";
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.bold = true;
        format.size = fontSize;
        format.font = "Arial";
        format.color = textColour;
        trace(textfield._x + "|" + textfield._y);
        textfield.setTextFormat(format);
    }
```

then ether one of these is called:

```
drawOption(_options[i]);
drawOption(_options[i],"hover");
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I thought I was overwriting the `textfield object` when using the same instance name as the previous one. It turns out this is not the case and the blocky look was many many textfields stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about color, it's about weight (bold) of the font. Have you tried embedding and anti-aliasing the fonts?

Comment: This might qualify as comment, rather than answer.

Comment: Tried embedding the font, and tried with both advanced and normal anti-aliasing. There is no change in the font format (both are bold) apart from colour as is shown in the script above.